# How do I disable Eclipse tooltips

Tags: eclipse

I never use tooltips, and the darn things always get in my way, so how do I disable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editors > Hovers

Untick Combined Hover.